# Error after installing package

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, bokeh, conda

Trying to install the dependencies required for the export_png method in Bokeh - that being Selenium, Pillow and PhantomJS. To get this to work I used the conda-forge version of Selenium and the -c anaconda phantomjs version.

After installing the required packages and attempting to export a Bokeh graph as a PNG I get the following error

```
'RuntimeError: PhantomJS is not present in PATH. Try "conda install phantomjs" or                            "npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt"
```

The only difference I can see for Phantomjs is that it's installed in the /anaconda/envs/virtualenv/bin opposed to my usual conda packages being installed in /anaconda/envs/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/. As such, is it struggling to locate phantomJS when I try to import because of the location of the library?

Would really appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it to your path?

```
export PATH=/anaconda/envs/virtualenv/bin:$PATH
```